# End processing when all processes are trying to get from the queue and the queue is empty?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to set up some processes that take an input and process it and the result of this result is another task that I want to be handled. Essentially each task results in zero or multiple new tasks (of the same type) eventually all tasks will yield no new tasks.

I figured a queue would be good for this so I have an input queue and a results queue to add the tasks that result in nothing new. At any one time, the queue might be empty but more could be added if another process is working on a task.

Hence, I only want it to end when all processes are simultaneously trying to get from the input queue.

I am completely new to both python multiprocessing and multiprocessing in general.

Edited to add a basic overview of what I mean:

```
class Consumer(Process):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name=name)

    def run():
        # This is where I would have the task try to get a new task off of the 
        # queue and then calculate the results and put them into the queue 
        # After which it would then try to get a new task and repeat

        # If this an all other processes are trying to get and the queue is 
        # empty That is the only time I know that everything is complete and can 
        # continue
        pass

def start_processing():
    in_queue = Queue()
    results_queue = Queue()
    consumers = [Consumer(str(i)) for i in range(cpu_count())]

    for i in consumers:
        i.start()

    # Wait for the above mentioned conditions to be true before continuing
```

Comment: At this point I only have the absolute skeleton code because this seems like something I need to work out before I move forward. Basically I have created the processes and the queues.

Comment: I have added some overview code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`JoinableQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue) has been designed to fit this purpose. Joining a `JoinableQueue` will block until there are tasks in progress.

You can use it as follows: the main process will spawn a certain amount of worker processes assigning them the `JoinableQueue`. The worker processes will use the queue to produce and consume new tasks. The main process will wait by joining the queue up until no more tasks are in progress. After that, it will terminate the worker processes and quit.

A very simplified example (pseudocode):

```
def consumer(queue):
    for task in queue.get():
        results = process_task(task)

        if 'more_tasks' in results:
            for new_task in results['more_tasks']:
                queue.put(new_task)

        # signal the queue that a task has been completed
        queue.task_done()  

def main():
    queue = JoinableQueue()

    processes = start_processes(consumer, queue)

    for task in initial_tasks:
        queue.put(task)

    queue.join()  # block until all work is done

    terminate_processes(processes)
```